# My Zorin OS dont want to accept my password that i have changed on the root recovery process

Tags: password-recovery, unlock

I have changed my password from root recovery mode , but now my password dont wanna unlock my computer, its just accepting it and ask me all over again and again, but its not unlocking

Comment: Zorin is not Ubuntu and therefor not supported here. Please consider asking for help at https://forum.zorin.com/